# Event when DataGridView cell scrolls out of view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a subclassed the DataGridViewCell and Column as `DataGridViewLabelCell` and `DataGridViewLabelColumn` which allows me to add Labels to be displayed within the cell. The idea is that I can stack labels on top of each other, use different colours, and also handle the click events on the individual labels. The `DataGridViewLabelCell` has the following code to add the labels:

```
public void AddLabel(string LabelText, Color BackColor, int Opacity, float ScalePosition, object Tag)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Visible = false;
    label.Text = LabelText;
    label.AutoSize = true;
    label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Opacity, BackColor);
    this.DataGridView.Controls.Add(label);

    LabelScalePostion labelScale = new LabelScalePostion();
    labelScale.Label = label;
    labelScale.ScalePosition = ScalePosition;

    label.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(DataGridViewCellLabel_DoubleClick);

    _labels.Add(labelScale);            
}

private void DataGridViewCellLabel_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;

    MessageBox.Show("ID = " + label.Tag.ToString());
}
```

And I have also overridden the `DataGridViewLabelCell`'s `Paint` event to position the labels:

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
    // Call the base class method to paint the default cell appearance.
    base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState,
        value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
        advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

    foreach (LabelScalePostion labelScale in _labels)
    {
        Label label = labelScale.Label;
        label.Visible = true;
        Point location = cellBounds.Location;
        location.Offset(40, (int)(cellBounds.Height * labelScale.ScalePosition));
        label.Location = location;
    }
}
```

This works in the sense that the label is not displayed until the cell that contains it is scrolled into view, but when it is scrolled back out of view then label stays at the top of the DGV. Therefore, I need some way of firing an event when the cell stops being displayed, however I can't find any such event.

I am currently handling this with the owning DataGridView's `Scroll` event as follows:

```
private void dgvItemView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    switch (_formType)
    {
        case FormType.DayView:
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvItemView.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewLabelCell cell = (DataGridViewLabelCell)row.Cells[0];

                foreach (DataGridViewLabelCell.LabelScalePostion labelScale in cell.Labels)
                    labelScale.Label.Visible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't feel right and to prove the point there is an ugly flicker when I scroll. Everything else works fine (appearance, Events etc) and I can tolerate the flicker, however I'm sure there must be a better way of achieving this.

Comment: This completely defeats the point of using a DGV.  Don't do it.  Use the CellPainting event instead.

Comment: Thanks for this - I don't think my post was clear enough as I was already using the Cell's Paint event to handle this. I've updated my question so hopefully it's a little clearer now

Comment: No, use it to draw the text that is now in the label.  Don't use label controls.

Comment: I understand your point, however I want to be able to handle click events on the individual labels, and one cell may potentially contain 4/5/6+ labels. As an example, I'm trying to achieve approximately the same effect as the way events are displayed on the Outlook 2010 calendar